# conditional rendering using an anonymous function (React)

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to get my head around condtional rendering and have started trying to implment this with a anonymous function.

pseudo code

```
if(statement)

render this

else

render something else
```

The condition works if the Boolean is set to isLoggedin = true but if false it throws

```
Error: DisplayUserAcountDetails(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null.
```

My actual code

```
render() {
    const isLoggedIn = false;
    if (isLoggedIn)
      return (
        <div>
          {(() => {
            if (isLoggedIn) {
              return (
                <ul>
                  {this.state.AccountDetails &&
                    this.state.AccountDetails.map(function(
                      AccountDetails,
                      index
                    ) {
                      return (
                        <div className="jumbotron">
                          <h3>Account Details</h3>
                          <li> Email: {AccountDetails.Email}</li>
                          <li> Name: {AccountDetails.NameOfUser}</li>
                          <li>
                            {" "}
                            Contact Number: {AccountDetails.ContactNumber}{" "}
                          </li>
                          <li>
                            <Link to="/profile-update-account-details">
                              <button>Update Account Details</button>
                            </Link>
                          </li>
                        </div>
                      );
                    })}
                </ul>
              );
            } else {
              return (
                <div>
                  <div>otherCase</div>
                  <h1>Not there</h1>
                </div>
              );
            }
          })()}
        </div>
      );
  }
```

Why is this throwing an error when one is rendered but the other loads fine? Is there some logic that I am missing?

Comment: You're not returning anything in case the first if condition fails. Also, I don't see any point of using an IIFE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First solution:**

```js
  render() {
    const isLoggedIn = false;

    if (!isLoggedIn) {
      return (
        <div>
          <div>otherCase</div>
          <h1>Not there</h1>
        </div>
      );
    }

    return (
      <ul>
        {this.state.AccountDetails &&
          this.state.AccountDetails.map(function(AccountDetails, index) {
            return (
              <div className="jumbotron">
                <h3>Account Details</h3>
                <li> Email: {AccountDetails.Email}</li>
                <li> Name: {AccountDetails.NameOfUser}</li>
                <li> Contact Number: {AccountDetails.ContactNumber} </li>
                <li>
                  <Link to="/profile-update-account-details">
                    <button>Update Account Details</button>
                  </Link>
                </li>
              </div>
            );
          })}
      </ul>
    );
```

**Second solution:**

```js
  render() {
    const isLoggedIn = false;
    return (
      <>
        {isLoggedIn ? (
          <ul>
            {this.state.AccountDetails &&
              this.state.AccountDetails.map(function(AccountDetails, index) {
                return (
                  <div className="jumbotron">
                    <h3>Account Details</h3>
                    <li> Email: {AccountDetails.Email}</li>
                    <li> Name: {AccountDetails.NameOfUser}</li>
                    <li> Contact Number: {AccountDetails.ContactNumber} </li>
                    <li>
                      <Link to="/profile-update-account-details">
                        <button>Update Account Details</button>
                      </Link>
                    </li>
                  </div>
                );
              })}
          </ul>
        ) : (
          <div>
            <div>otherCase</div>
            <h1>Not there</h1>
          </div>
        )}
      </>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

1) You are missing curly braces {  } of the if else statement.

2) You should check out the ternary operator in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you are missing a ELSE statement.
Have a look:

```js
render() {
    const isLoggedIn = false;
    if (isLoggedIn)
      return (
        <div>
          {(() => {
            if (isLoggedIn) {
              return (
                <ul>
                  {this.state.AccountDetails &&
                    this.state.AccountDetails.map(function(
                      AccountDetails,
                      index
                    ) {
                      return (
                        <div className="jumbotron">
                          <h3>Account Details</h3>
                          <li> Email: {AccountDetails.Email}</li>
                          <li> Name: {AccountDetails.NameOfUser}</li>
                          <li>
                            {" "}
                            Contact Number: {AccountDetails.ContactNumber}{" "}
                          </li>
                          <li>
                            <Link to="/profile-update-account-details">
                              <button>Update Account Details</button>
                            </Link>
                          </li>
                        </div>
                      );
                    })}
                </ul>
              );
            } else {
              return (
                <div>
                  <div>otherCase</div>
                  <h1>Not there</h1>
                </div>
              );
            }
          })()}
        </div>
      );
      else 
      {
          return (null)
      }
  }
```